Mysql update using an inner never ends infinite loop, but select works
I am trying to update this mysql table column, from storing an employee value as a name string to an ID with a foreign key. This is my query:
UPDATE 
    sale 
inner JOIN 
    employee on sale.salesperson = concat(employee.first_name,' ',employee.last_name) 
SET 
    salesperson_employee_id = employee.employee_id;

But the query never ends, It cant be that insane because there are only about 10,000 or so rows in sale, and 100+ in employees. Whats troubling me is doing a select with the same join runs almost instantly, so if not the join why is this never ending?
select 
    * 
from 
    sale
INNER JOIN 
    employee on sale.salesperson = concat(employee.first_name,' ',employee.last_name)

This query runs in milliseconds, and returns all 12,000 rows with the correct join. Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Provide EXPLAINs for both queries and CREATE TABLE for both tables.

there are only about 10,000 or so rows in sale, and 100+ in employees But returns all 12,000 rows - where more 2000 rows are taken from?

Try this qurey. Because of the CONCAT in yours, he has to process all entries with CONCAT for every JOIN and can then compare them. Also set a combining INDEX to first_name + lastname
UPDATE 
    sale 
inner JOIN 
    employee on
      employee.first_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(sale.salesperson, ' ', 1)
   AND
      employee.last_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(sale.salesperson, ' ', -1)
SET 
    salesperson_employee_id = employee.employee_id;


This would affect the select as well, but that's quick according to the OP. The dataset is small.

This instantly worked, for my own future reference, isnt concat and substring_index both O(1)?  So how did changing concat to substring speed it up by this much?

@Oirampok - you first get the entry from the sale table and do a JOIN to the employee table. In your example you say "Assemble all entries from employee (first + lastname) and compare them with the entry that is currently current in sale. So he has to put them all together first, and do it anew for each entry. In my example you can He has to look directly into the joined table with the index and find the entry. So if possible, NEVER carry out calculations in the join with the joined table. This ALWAYS results in a FULL TABLE SCAN for the joined table and that for each entry. +next comment

@Oirampok -  So in your example 10000 * 100 = 1000000 searches without index. For me only 10000 * 1 = 10000 searches and that with index
